# How to create a written transcript of a BBC radio broadcast where the media player does not provide Closed Captioning?

Tags: audio, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Am not entirely sure that this is the site to ask this question. If it is not, kindly migrate the question to the appropriate SE site.

---

On [June 15, 2018 BBC World Service Weekend](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/w172w71sbnxm1rz) aired a program that am trying to acquire or create a textual transcript of. The media player does not provide Closed Captioning capabilities.

Am specifically interested creating a textual transcript of the broadcast beginning at 8:50 and concluding at 11:30.

Given that using `SpeechRecognition` of the Web Speech API at [Chromium browser involves sending the recorded audio to a remote server](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=816095), would rather avoid that option.

What are possible approaches for acquiring or creating a textual transcript of the above described audio media?

Answer (score -1):

One way would be to use Dragon Dictate to do the dictation. Software isn't expensive but they have no trial option.